# Dimension issue when using .apply(value_counts, bin=x)

Tags: python, pandas, apply, bins

I am trying to apply value_counts to the following dataframe using bins

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2.apply(pd.value_counts, normalize=True, bins=[0,25,50,75,101]).sort_values(by=['A'], ascending=False)
```

However when I do this i get the following error:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5) into shape (4)

The code works fine when I am not trying to use bins.

Comment: For me it working nice in pandas 0.22.0, what is your pandas version?

Comment: @jezrael What's your NumPy version?

Comment: I think that if this works at all, it works by accident - in the documentation, `bins` is stated to take an optional integer.

Comment: @miradulo - `numpy: 1.12.1`, but just realised it is data dependend issue, if some bins missing raise error.

Comment: Just realised that I am using pandas version 0.20.3. I will update and see if it works

Comment: I feel like something weird is happening with `df.apply` here.

Comment: @miradulo - yes, it looks like bug, but sorting index with list comprehension and concat working.

Comment: @jezrael I'm way too tired to look closely at this today but I might tomorrow if I've got time :)

Comment: I updated my pandas package and it is still not working but I will use your workaround. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like bug.

But for me working [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with list comprehension and [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
L = [pd.value_counts(df2[x], normalize=True, bins=[0,25,50,75,101]).sort_index() for x in df2]
b = pd.concat(L, 1).sort_values(by=['A'], ascending=False)
```

Or add `sort_index` to `value_counts` in `apply`:

```
b=df2.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x, normalize=True, bins=[0,25,50,75,101]).sort_index())
```

---

```
print (b)
                    A      B      C      D
(-0.001, 25.0]  0.263  0.273  0.278  0.259
(25.0, 50.0]    0.251  0.254  0.234  0.255
(50.0, 75.0]    0.250  0.257  0.240  0.249
(75.0, 101.0]   0.236  0.216  0.248  0.237
```

Comment: Thanks i missed the sort index +1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround not the exact answer:

```
In [174]: pd.concat([df2[i].value_counts(normalize=True,bins=[0,25,50,75,101]).sort_index() for i in df2.columns],axis=1)
Out[174]: 
                    A      B      C      D
(-0.001, 25.0]  0.253  0.231  0.238  0.270
(25.0, 50.0]    0.263  0.246  0.260  0.248
(50.0, 75.0]    0.264  0.278  0.239  0.241
(75.0, 101.0]   0.220  0.245  0.263  0.241
```